# Can't get fullpage.js work with Pure Css Parallax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, fullpage.js

I downloaded [fullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) from gitHub, and it is such a great thing, but I needed to add some parallax, so I found [this one](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/), cool stuff as well, but there is a problem with connecting **fullpage** with this **css3 parallax**. They don't work together. Mb anyone could help...

Stuff like `scrollbar: true` and `css3: true` I've done, but still.

P.s. sorry for my English

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work together"?  Specific issues you're trying to solve?

Comment: When im trying to add this ccs3 parallax, parallax doesnt work, so i cant understand why, and how fix it.

Comment: The issue is on your side for sure. When using `scrollBar:true` in fullPage.js it acts as any other normal scrolling website. So, try to use that parallax effect in a normal website and then just apply it to your fullPage.js site.

Comment: There's now a [parallax extension](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html) to create parallax effects!